# antd rowspan is not applied in the next page

Tags: reactjs, antd

[image]

```
<Table
    columns={columns}
    dataSource={dataSource}
    bordered
    rowKey="id"
  ></Table>
```

This is my Table

I'm bundling rowSpan for data with the same date.

However, if I move to the next page, the rowspan applied with columns is not applied. How can I solve this problem?

In addition, dataSource is being received as axios api.
This is the code to combine the date rowSpan from columns to one.

```
{
  title: 'date',
  dataIndex: 'today',
  render: (value, row, index) => {
    const obj = {
      children: value,
      props: {},
    };
    if (index >= 1 && value === dataSource[index - 1].today) {
      obj.props.rowSpan = 0;
    } else {
      for (
        let i = 0;
        index + i !== dataSource.length &&
        value === dataSource[index + i].today;
        i += 1
      ) {
        obj.props.rowSpan = i + 1;
      }
    }
    return obj;
  },
},
```

Comment: This is difficult for anyone other than yourself to reproduce. Can you reproduce this without your api call response? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Could you explain the word reproduction more?

Comment: By that, I mean making the error occur again, repeatedly and consistently whenever the same conditions are met. If you write the above program using sample constant data (not the API response data), does this error still occur?

Comment: And if so, could you show the sample data you used to reproduce the error?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-wilbur-3wlpf?file=/src/App.js

I get the same error even though I haven't used the api. The date is not divided on page 2. how to solve it? Thank you for your continued support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of the bug is that the `index` parameter passed into the column's `render(text, record, index)` function is scoped to the current "pagination" page, not the entire table. That is: when you navigate to next page, the value of `index` "restarts" from 0 - 9, whether it is the first page or not.

So, if you want your rowspan logic to apply in other pages, you need to factor in current pagination state. You'll need to handle the table's `onChange` event (which is called with the current pagination of the table) and use that information to update your render function using logic such as this:

```
const trueIndex = index + paginationInfo.pageSize * (paginationInfo.current - 1);
```

Here's a working example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-mclaren-zcol9?file=/src/App.js:2183-2274